# Trouble using Synology OpenVPN from network-manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I've setup `network-manager-openvpn` and `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` no problem, popped in my OpenVPN info and cert, and it connects just fine. Running `ip addr` shows:

```
11: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5/32 brd 10.8.0.6 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

...which matches up with other machines connecting to this VPN (on OSX). The other machines are not currently having any issues, I should add.

Anyways, once connected, I can ping myself at the IP handed out by the DHCP (10.8.0.6) but nothing else, including the gateway (10.8.0.5). No other services on the network are accessible via the VPN, and no outside sides are accessible. Where would I begin troubleshooting?

Comment: I have the same problem.